# Is this a bug in powershell's TrimStart?

Tags: powershell

Forgive me if I am wrong to be frustrated about this. But, this is why I hate trying to do anything remotely complex in a scripting language like PowerShell. It's a never ending battle with unpredictability.

So, here it is:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      15063  632 

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $testpath = "\\a-server-unc\home\auser\Outlook Data\archive1 - Copy.pst"

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $(Split-path -path $testpath -Parent)
\\a-server-unc\home\auser\Outlook Data #Ok - Looks good

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $(Split-path -path $testpath -Parent).TrimStart("\\a-server-unc")
home\auser\Outlook Data   # Where did my slash go?

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $(Split-path -path $testpath -parent).TrimStart("\\a-server-unc\home")
Outlook Data  # Wait - What the...

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $testpath
\\a-server-unc\home\auser\Outlook Data\archive1 - Copy.pst # Yep - I'm not insane. Powershell is eating my characters.

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $testpath = "\\a-server-unc\home\aloser\Outlook Data\archive1 - Copy.pst"  #Let's try changing the string a little

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $(Split-path -path $testpath -Parent).TrimStart("\\a-server-unc\home")
loser\Outlook Data   # I must be insane

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> $(Split-path -path $testpath -Parent).TrimStart("`\`\a-server-unc`\home") #Certainly escaping the slashes will fix this?
loser\Outlook Data   # Nope, more hours wasted on unpredictable behavior
```

Now clearly there is some strange, "perfectly normal" behavior here, but I'm getting a little tired of Powershell eating my strings.

What's the magic potion here?

Comment: "*But, this is why I hate trying to do anything remotely complex in a scripting language like PowerShell. It's a never ending battle with unpredictability.*" - String.TrimStart() in .Net has been there at least 3 years before PowerShell existed  (15 years+). It's the same in C# and VB.Net, Python and PHP. It doesn't appear to exist (in either form) in JavaScript, Java, Swift, Ruby, C++ std::string; the only language I've found so far is Go with a choice of both versions; what language(s) are you coming from that lead you to predict it to be different and describe it as 'unpredictable'?

Comment: Anyway, `.Trim()` removes whitespace from both ends of a string - that's space, tab, newline. Or it can be extended to remove specific characters, e.g. remove any kind of quote characters, or any kind of parens/brackets from around both sides of a string. In that context, an array of chars makes sense and restricting that to .TrimStart and .TrimEnd make more sense. It would make less sense to generalise the other way and have a function which can remove a fixed string from one end become a function which can remove a fixed string from both ends - because that's not all that useful.

Comment: `-replace "^\\\\a-server-unc"` would do it, with the caveats that it's regular expression pattern matching so special characters need escaping or `[regex]::Escape()`'ing, and it's case-insensitive by default (`.Replace()` is case sensitive).

Comment: It's always helpful to read the documentation first before asking someone if there is a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the expected behavior.

As per documentation

**String.TrimStart Method (Char())**

Removes all leading occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current String object. - [source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx)

To trim a contiguous string, you could use -replace using regex

```
"\a-server-unc\home\user\a-server-unc\Outlook Data\archive1" -replace "^\\a-server-unc\\",''
```

The output would result in

> home\user\a-server-unc\Outlook Data\archive1

The key character being to include the `^` to signify that the occurrence is right after the start of of the line and not anywhere (that's why the second occurence of my replace stayed.)

If you prefer to avoid regex, you would need something like this:

```
function TrimStart([String]$InputObject,[String]$Value){
    if ($InputObject.StartsWith($Value)) {
        return $InputObject.Substring($value.Length,$InputObject.Length - $value.Length)
    }
    else{
        return $InputObject
    }
}
```

Here's is the difference between the two in action. 
$ConceptString = 'This is a very long string that also happens to be a complete sentence !!!'

```
write-host $ConceptString.TrimStart('This is a very long string') -ForegroundColor Cyan
#Output: ppens to be a complete sentence !!!
Write-host $(TrimStart $ConceptString -Value 'This is a very long string')  -ForegroundColor Green
#output: that also happens to be a complete sentence !!!
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a built in function in PowerShell to do this. I ended up going with `.Replace ($startstring, "")` because I am confident the sequence of characters will only exist at the beginning of my strings. But, your solution is more precise and does it properly. Thanks.

Comment: see my edit at the top. Actually, replace support regex so you could have a powershell built-in one-liner replace that target only the start of the line.

Answer (score 1):

See `TrimStart()` documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimstart.aspx

In particular, note that `TrimStart()` takes a character array as input, not a string (as you seem to be expecting):

```
public string TrimStart(
    params char[] trimChars
)
```

So `TrimStart()` is removing characters, not an entire string.

See, for example, the output of:

```
$testpath = "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhelloooooooo".TrimStart("h")
```

It outputs:

> elloooooooo

The solution is to use the `Replace()` function instead.

One such way to do that:

```
$testpath = "\\a-server-unc\home\auser\Outlook Data\archive1 - Copy.pst"
$basepath = "\\a-server-unc\"
[regex]$pattern = [regex]::escape($basepath)
# pattern is regex version of string you want to replace
# .replace("string to replace", "replacing string", numberOfReplacements)
# i.e. only replace the 1st instance
$newPath = $pattern.replace($testpath, [string]::Empty, 1)
```

Outputs for `$newPath`:

> home\auser\Outlook Data\archive1 - Copy.pst

Comment: Thank you, I did just come across that and am reading on it. Do you have a proper alternative to reliably removing a string from the beginning of another string?

Comment: As an addendum you'll have the expected results by using `.Replace()` and replace with an empty string. For example: `.Replace('\\a-server-unc',
 [string]::Empty)`

Comment: This is an OK solution, and I have gone with it. But it does not account for the substring occurring within the main string in another location other than the beginning. This could have unpredictable results. Thanks though.

Comment: I don't understand your example. That is not the correct output for the input you provided. Your example directly contradicts the previous statements...

Comment: @Cole9350 Sorry, I was editing in a hurry and I made a mistake. I fixed the output now.